# ¿Por qué "insano" se define primero como "perjudicial para la salud" si la acepción "loco, demente" es la que histórica y actualmente más se usa?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, historia, dle

Al leer el titular del artículo [¿Son los helados realmente tan insanos como la gente dice?](http://www.eldiario.es/consumoclaro/cuidarse/helados-azucar-aceite_de_palma_0_654085364.html) di un pequeño respingo. ¡Usa *insano* como antónimo de *sano*!

Resulta que llevo bastante tiempo oyendo usar esta palabra a la gente para designar algo loco. Creía que era una palabra de nuevo cuño, venida del inglés [*insane*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/insane) que designa algo o alguien loco, descabellado...

Pero hete aquí que el DLE me dio dos sorpresas: la acepción antónima de *sano* es correcta y que la lo de loco, descabellado también existe:

> [**insano, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LjQW8fk)
>   Del lat. insānus 'loco'.
>   1. adj. Perjudicial para la salud.
>   2. adj. Loco, demente.

Una breve revisión del NTLLE me indica que se usa lo de *loco, demente* desde que hay diccionarios. Viendo la etimología parece una cosa clara.

Como decía antes, también me sorprendió que la primera acepción sea la antónima de salud, pues rara vez la he oído. El mapa de diccionarios me dio un poco la razón al indicar que esta entrada se intrdujo en la edición de 1992 del diccionario, poniéndola directamente como acepción principal. Mirando otra vez en el NTLLE vi que apareció:

- primero en el Academia Usual de 1984 como sinónimo de *insalubre*, y
- en el Academia Manual tomo IV de ese mismo año de segunda acepción como *Que no reúne condiciones higiénicas y es perjudicial para la salud*.
- y ya en 1992 como primera acepción.

Mi pregunta es, pues: ¿por qué se "subió" tan rápidamente la acepción sinónima de *insalubre*, pasándola de no existente a preferente? ¿No es acaso hoy en día más utilizada la acepción de *loco, demente*?

Comment: Yo, sinceramente, nunca he oído usar esta palabra como sinónimo de *loco, demente* en español, aunque acepto que el significado exista. Por otro lado, que no apareciera en el diccionario hasta hace poco no significa que no se usara; las palabras formadas con prefijos no suelen aparecer a menos que tengan un significado diferente al que se deduce directamente dle significado del prefijo.

Comment: Por mi parte es al revés. Yo nunca he oído _insano_ como sinónimo de "nocivo" (acá en Chile), y las pocas veces que la he oído se refiere a "loco" . Debe ser una diferencia geográfica.

Answer (score 2):

La aceptación se debe a que el prefijo -**in** proviene del latín -**in** (valga la redundancia) la cual significa "no". Esta se relaciona con una raíz indoeuropea -**ne** y esta presente en el prefijo griego  **α** que significa negación.

Al utilizarla como prefijo de un adjetivo, este se convertiría en la negativa del adjetivo. Por ello, es fácil aceptar estas palabras de manera rápida.

Insalubre es entonces la negación de la salud, esto es algo que perjudique la salud. No obstante, aunque es cierto que el adjetivo más utilizado es loco o demente, esto no implica que sea incorrecta la palabra insalubre.

Answer (score 2):

Soy hablante de dialecto castellano y creo que nunca he usado `insano` como sinónimo de loco. Siempre para mí algo insano es algo insalubre, poco saludable. Su uso como loco me suena a anglicismo sin traducir, no sabía que se usara realmente.

Por el contrario como sinónimos de loco puede usar:

- desquiciado
- demente
- majareta
- lunático
- mal de la cabeza